# Radwindow Autotmatically close while i changed combobox value

Tags: telerik

i have use usercontrol inside the telerik:radwindow.

radwindow using in parent page. i have using combobox control in user control page. radwindow automatically closing while the combo box value changed.

My code is here.

```
<telerik:RadWindowManager ID="radWinApproveforSite" runat="server">
      <Windows>
           <telerik:RadWindow ID="RadWinSiteApproval" align="center" Skin="Sunset" Style="text-align: center" Behaviors="Minimize, Maximize,Close" Modal="true"              ReloadOnShow="true" ShowContentDuringLoad="false" runat="server" Width="700" Height="565" VisibleOnPageLoad="false">
        <ContentTemplate>
               <div id="divPopup" style="height: 500px">
                      <table>
                           <tr>
                              <td>

                     <UC:SiteApprove ID="UCSiteApprove" runat="server"</UC:SiteApprove>


                              </td>
                           </tr>
                       </table>

                </div>
        </ContentTemplate>
        </telerik:RadWindow>
    </Windows>
</telerik:RadWindowManager>
```

my combobox property auotopostback=true. because one combo box related to another combo box.   i need to won't close radwindow. Thanks advance..:)

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that you're opening the radwindow using javascript. When opened using javascript, whenever the page is posted back to, the (`visible`) state of the `RadWindow` is reverted to how it was when the page was previously posted back. Unfortunately this means that posting back within a `RadWindow` can be problematic; you could change the `VisibleOnPageLoad` setting to `true` when the drop down list posts back, however that means if the page is posted back to again after closing the radwindow it will reopen on those postabacks, there are many ways of getting round this, my preferences would be one of the following:

1. The easiest is to always use URL's to define the content of the `RadWindow`, this can have the added benefit reducing the viewstate and performance of the page as it can be loaded on demand.
2. Create a control which represents the visibility state of the `RadWindow` (e.g. a `checkbox`) and on each load ensure the visibility is set to match the setting defined by this control.
3. Don't use `AutoPostBack`, do the update of the second drop down list using javascript, rebinding the results or using a web service to populate according to the selected values.

There are other fixes would probably use either an `AjaxPanel` or `AjaxManager` and require a reasonable amount of code to be provided.

Answer (score 0):

Use AJAX in the content template, or move the UC to a full page you will load in the RadWindow: http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/radwindow-ajaxifying.html. That's just a line to add a RadAjaxPanel right inside the ContentTemplate.